# Optgroups with dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all I have the following table

```
--------------------------------------------
|ID|point_name|point_address|point_category|
|01|bobs      |7362 178 st  |House         |
|02|Greegs    |1123 118 Ave |Store         |
And so on
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to use the optgroup function on a combo box so that users can get results categorized while they search.

My code so far:

```
<select id="combobox">
<?php
$end_point   = "SELECT * FROM points";
$q_end_point = $conn->query($end_point);
$q_end_point->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while ($row = $q_end_point->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['point_address'] . "'>" . $row['point_name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

I don't know how to go about adding optgroup however, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: It looks fine it you have </select> in the end, what's the error you got?

Comment: what type do you want to categorized ? point_category ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

/* First you need to format your array like bellow*/

$array = array(
    array(
        'category' => "House",
        'result' => array(
            1,
            2,
            3
        )
    ),
    array(
        'category' => "Store",
        'result' => array(
            4,
            5,
            6
        )
    )
);

?>


<select>
    <?php foreach($array as $value): ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $value['category'];?>">
        <?php foreach($value[ 'result'] as $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>">
            <?php echo $value;?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </optgroup>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/2sJpmJgs) [***JsFiddle Html Output***](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/Yq3vH/)